# How to download a topological map for a country (as defined by GADM)?

Tags: map

I'd like to download in GeoTiff format, but I'm not fussy. I'd like to use Julia, and failing that Matlab, but, again, not fussy.

What's important is that I be able to download topological data and finish with a cropped dataset. The cropping should follow the administrative boundaries, as in the below picture: [image]

The frustrating thing here is that I did this before. I made that map of Michigan, from data I downloaded online. But I cannot for the life of me remember how I did it, nor can I find appropriate notes (all I've got is some references to R code, but I've never installed R so I know that can't be it).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I downloaded R console ([macOS binaries](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)) and then used the below code (which was heavily adapted from https://github.com/sikli/srtm_country):

(NOTE: I possibly had to install the `raster` package but don't recall and don't know how to uninstall/reinstall so I can be sure I'm checking correctly.)

The program is easy to use, just modify the `countryName`, `stateName`, and `countyName`. These map to the 0th, 1st, and 2nd levels of administrative boundaries. For instance:

- `AUT` for Austria
- `FRA`>>`Bourgogne-Franche-Comté`, for the Burgundy-Franche-Comté region in France
- `USA`>>`Massachusetts`>>`Essex` for Essex County in Massachusetts, USA

Then be sure to set the `boundaryLevel` to represent the number of administrative levels required. So in the above example, for Austria set `boundaryLevel<-0`, Burgundy-Franche-Comté region in France set `boundaryLevel<-1`, and Essex County in Massachusetts, USA set `boundaryLevel<-2`.

(NOTE: Nothing bad will happen if you set all three level names, but only use the zeroth or 1st level.)

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(rasterVis)


#------------SETTINGS--------------

#Specify target ISO country code and path to downloaded shapefile

shp          <- shapefile("srtm/tiles.shp")       #Path to SRTM Tiles (can be found in subfolder srtm)

countryName <- "USA"
stateName <- "Kentucky"
countyName <- "Clark"


boundaryLevel <- 2

#------------EXECUTE FROM HERE--------------
# Determine if this is a 0th-level administrative boundary
if (boundaryLevel==0){
    message("Configured for zeroth-level subdivide")
    
    # Download the country
    usa0<-getData('GADM', country=countryName, level=0)
    country <- usa0
  
    downloadBorders <- country
    cropBorders <- country
    fileName <- cropBorders$NAME_0
} else {
    
    # Download the first subdivide in the country, usually a "state" or "region"
    usa1<-getData('GADM', country=countryName, level=1)
    state1 <- usa1[usa1$NAME_1 %in% c(stateName), ] 
    downloadBorders <- state1
    
    # Determine if this is a 1st-level or 2nd-level administrative boundary
    if (boundaryLevel==1) {
        message("Configured for first-level subdivide")
        
        cropBorders <- state1
        fileName <- cropBorders$NAME_1
    } else {
        message("Configured for second-level subdivide")
        # Download the second subdivide in the country, usually a "county"
        usa2<-getData('GADM', country=countryName, level=2)
        state2 <- usa2[usa2$NAME_1 %in% c(stateName), ]
        county <- state2[state2$NAME_2 %in% c(countyName), ]

        cropBorders <- county
        fileName <- cropBorders$NAME_2
    }
}

# Some console spew
message(paste("Downloading boundaries for admin area: ", fileName))

#Intersect country geometry with tile grid
intersects <- gIntersects(downloadBorders, shp, byid=T)
tiles      <- shp[intersects[,1],]


#Download tiles
message(paste("Downloading SRTM data for admin area: ", fileName))
srtm_list  <- list()
for(i in 1:length(tiles)) {
  lon <- extent(tiles[i,])[1]  + (extent(tiles[i,])[2] - extent(tiles[i,])[1]) / 2
  lat <- extent(tiles[i,])[3]  + (extent(tiles[i,])[4] - extent(tiles[i,])[3]) / 2
  
  tile <- getData('SRTM', 
                  lon=lon, 
                  lat=lat)
  
  srtm_list[[i]] <- tile
}


#Mosaic
message("Mosaicing...")
srtm_list$fun <- mean 
srtm_mosaic   <- do.call(mosaic, srtm_list)

#Crop to country borders
message("Cropping...")
srtm_crop     <- mask(srtm_mosaic, cropBorders)

message("Saving to disk...")
outFile <- paste(fileName, ".tiff", sep="")
writeRaster(srtm_crop, outFile, format="GTiff", datatype='FLT4S', overwrite=TRUE)

# Final console spew
message("")
message("**************")
message(paste("Successfully saved to: ", outFile))
message("**************")
message("")
message("")
```

(After downloading, the GeoTiff can be imported into a program like [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) and then extracted to an STL with, e.g., [DEMto3D](https://demto3d.com/en/).)